# visual studio 2015 CTP Freezing on javascript editor

Tags: javascript, .net, freeze, ram, visual-studio-2015

Everytime i open a javascript file and the editor opens up, my ram jumps until my computer runs out.  I disabled all 3rd party extensions and cleared my nuget cache, and restarted my computer.  Anyone have any pointers as to what might be happening?

Comment: Have you used the send a frown?  I have used it a few times and got a patch for one of the issues I was seeing.

Comment: @JohnKoerner what is send a frown?

Comment: The little smiley face in the top right corner of VS 2015.  When you have the issue, note what you were doing and click the submit a frown link under the smiley face.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5 & 6 and resolved the issue by closing Visual Studios,  opening the JavaScript files till I found one that was not proper JavaScript because I had saved it in the middle of editing a line and deleted the unfinished line.  After Restarting Visual Studios the issue was resolved for me.

It was a small project so there weren't too many .js files to check yet.